# OWASP Decoder issue in JSP

Tags: owasp

I am using OWASP encoder to encode my strings, but the string is not decoding in JSP pages. It is showing as it is like encoded string, e.g. My original String is `l&t.com`. After encoding, the string is `"l'&amp';t.com"`, but again it should decode in JSP which is not happening. Can any one please suggest. I am using utf-8 meta tag also in JSP .

Any help much much appreciated .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this. We need to add escapeXml = false for the respective value, then this will be resolved.